# Troubles with Sidecar (iPad as second monitor)

Tags: macos, ipad, sidecar

New here and recently switched to Apple. I'm using a Macbook Air M2 (15") and iPad Air (2023).

I have several very annoying and strange issues when using Sidecar (MacOS built-in feature which should enable me to use the iPad as a second monitor):

- During use, my Macbook freezes frequently for several seconds (both video, mouse and keyboard become unresponsive);
- During use, SideCard on the iPad totally freezes and I have to reconnect to get i working again;
- Since replacing the Macbook (with the same model, to check if it was a hardware issue) I have to go all the way to monitor settings instead of just using the monitor icon in the menu bar.

Any help is greatly appreciated! I use this intensively, so fixing this would really help me out. Thanks!

Comment: MacBook Air M2 - 15" (Sonoma 14.1.2 (23B92))


iPad Air (5th gen)(iPadOS 16.6)

Comment: Please limit to one issue per question and include your hardware and operating system info as part of the original question